# How to select and manipulate column in table jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

```js
jQuery('.rolly').hover( function() { 
  var colorclass = jQuery(this).attr('colorclass'); 
  var colorcolumn = jQuery(this).attr('colorcolumn'); 
  var selector = "#table-struct tr td:nth-child(" + colorcolumn + ")";
  jQuery(selector).toggleClass(colorclass); 
});
```

```html
<img id="img1" class="rolly" title="Biddr" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.brealtime.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/biddr_plus_hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.brealtime.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/biddr_plus-image.png';" src="http://www.brealtime.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/biddr_plus-image.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" />
<img class="rolly" title="bRT Biddr" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.brealtime.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/brt_Biddr_hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.brealtime.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/brt_Biddr-image.png';" src="http://www.brealtime.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/brt_Biddr-image.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" />
<img class="rolly" title="Biddr API" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.brealtime.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/biddr_API_hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.brealtime.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/biddr_API-image.png';" src="http://www.brealtime.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/biddr_API-image.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" />

<!-- Begin Table -->  

<div id="table-struct">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-right" style="margin-right: 70px;">
    <thead>

      <tr>
        <td>SIMPLE INTEGRATION:seamless
          setup process to get started</td>
        <td align="center">X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
      </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>NO ADVERSE EFFECTS OF LATENCY:
          publishers can set the overall
          timeout threshold</td>
        <td>Across All Header
          Bidding Partners</td>
        <td>For The bRT
          Integration Only</td>
        <td>** Controlled by
          Publisher**</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>HORIZONTAL INTEGRATION: unlike
          some integrations that will
          compete only for first look or
          cookie matching, we compete
          on every impression served</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>ACCOUNT MANAGEMENT: access to
          a technical &amp; operational
          resource to ensure rapid and
          effective support</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>ACCESS THE bRT MARKETPLACE:
          drive significantly more
          competition with access to
          bRT’s unparalleled proprietary
          programmatic and managed
          advertiser demand</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>BILL OFF PUBLISHER’S AD SERVER:
          ensures no risk of revenue
          loss, guaranteeing results
          yielded are purely incremental</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>MEDIATION: we optimize all
          partners to maximize
          competition and drive the
          highest CPM possible</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>EQUAL PLAYING FIELD: create
          parity and fairness for all
          demand partners competing
          at the same level</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>INCREASED OPERATIONAL
          EFFICIENCY: a publisher’s ops
          team does not need to worry
          about multiple integrations,
          managing discrepancies &amp; the
          adverse performance effects
          of working with multiple
          header providers</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I'm doing this in a WordPress post 
So I'm trying to select a full column when a mouse hovers over a particular image  and change the color of the column with jquery. So when I hover over the first image it turns the second column red, when I hover over the second it turns green and so on. Any suggestions? I have images with the class 'rolly' and have coded some jQuery logic as well. Just not sure if the logic will make sense when I apply it or not. So far I've been a bit unsuccessful.

Comment: You missing the document.ready statement

Comment: @DinoMyte The script is at the end of markup, i.e. it comes after the target elements, in this case there is no need to use document.ready.

Comment: @Orok Ukpong : Try this : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/nhoo6rhc/. You might need to set the colorcolumn accordingly

Comment: I do not see 'colorclass' or 'colorcolumn' on your rolly images?  Also as these are non-standard attributes they should be prefixed with `data-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class .rolly doesn't have an attribute 'colorclass'. In fact, what you want to do is identify columns, so why don't you mark the table data as such? Like this:

```
<tr>
<td class="col-1">NO ADVERSE EFFECTS OF LATENCY:
publishers can set the overall
timeout threshold</td>
<td class="col-2">Across All Header
Bidding Partners</td>
<td class="col-3">For The bRT
Integration Only</td>
<td class="col-4">** Controlled by
Publisher**</td>
</tr>
```

and then have your script change the background of the particular column class when you roll over and image? Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img1").hover(function(){
        $(".col-2").css('background-color', 'red');
    }, function() {
        $(".col-2").css('background-color', 'white');
    });
    $("#img2").hover(function(){
        $(".col-3").css('background-color', 'red');
    }, function() {
        $(".col-3").css('background-color', 'white');
    });
    $("#img3").hover(function(){
        $(".col-4").css('background-color', 'red');
    }, function() {
        $(".col-4").css('background-color', 'white');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The images which have '.rolly' class don't have 'colorcolumn' and 'colorclass' attributes.

So you need to add them to the images like following.

```
<img id="img1" class="rolly" title="Biddr" colorcolumn="1" colorclass="red" onmouseove .... >
<img class="rolly" title="bRT Biddr" colorcolumn="2" colorclass="blue"  onouseover.....>
<img class="rolly" title="Biddr API" colorcolumn="3" colorclass="green"  on....>
```

The jQuery code what you made will work.
According to the above code snippt, you need to add color style classes like following.

```
.red{
   color: red;
}
.blue{
   color: blue;
}
.green{
   color: green;
}
```

You can modify color values as you want.